# Error convert function from if else to switch statement

Tags: javascript

I'm creating sentences for a chatbot and I need to replace the IF with a Switch, I've tried a few things, but I'm not familiar with JavaScript.

```
function chatbotResponse() {
  talking = true;
  botMessage = "Desculpe não entendi"; //the default message

  if (lastUserMessage === 'hi' || lastUserMessage =='hello') {
    const hi = ['hi','howdy','hello']
    botMessage = hi[Math.floor(Math.random()*(hi.length))];;
  }

  if (lastUserMessage === 'name') {
    botMessage = 'My name is ' + botName;
  }
}
```

**I've tried it as follows:**

```
switch(lastUserMessage) {
  case lastUserMessage === 'hi':
    botMessage = 'My name is ' + botName;
    break;
  case lastUserMessage === 'hi'
   botMessage = 'My name is ' + botName;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't check for equality in `case`, that's why you have used the `switch` statement so that it will check automatically. So you just need to use the value with which the `lastUserMessage` will get check. You can also add a `default` case. If there is no match, the default code block is executed.

```js
const lastUserMessage = "hi";
const botName = "Alexa";
let botMessage;

switch (lastUserMessage) {
  case "hi":
    botMessage = "Hi, My name is " + botName;
    break;
  case "hello":
    botMessage = "Hello, My name is " + botName;
    break;
}

console.log(botMessage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the [switch documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) ?

You don't need to use the `===` operator, the switch-case already does it for you

```
switch (lastUserMessage) {
  case 'hello':
    botMessage = 'Hello, my name is ' + botName;
    break;
  case 'name':
    botMessage = 'My name is ' + botName;
    break;
  default:
    botMessage = 'default message'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the `switch` starts to compare `lastUserMessage` from the first case variant that is `hi`.  That’s a match, so the execution starts from case `hi` until the nearest break.

If there is no break then the execution continues with the next case without any check.

```js
const lastUserMessage = "hi";
const botName = "Alexa";
let botMessage;

switch (lastUserMessage) {
  case 'hi':
  case 'hello':
    botMessage = 'Hello, my name is ' + botName;
    break;
  case 'name':
    botMessage = 'My name is ' + botName;
    break;
}

console.log(botMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct syntax for implementing switch-case statements. You can correct your syntax this way:

```
switch (lastUserMessage) {
  case "hi":
    botMessage = "My name is " + botName;
    break;
}
```

You can refer to the official MDN Docs to learn more about switch-case statements:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch